# Why can't I deploy React app through Netlify due to exit code 1?

Tags: reactjs, npm, netlify

So I'm trying to deploy my React project through Netlify. I've searched for solutions to my error, but couldn't find one that solves.

So below is the log.

```
(...)
12:21:05 PM: $ npm run build
12:21:06 PM: > synergy_react@0.1.0 build /opt/build/repo/synergy_react
12:21:06 PM: > react-scripts build
12:21:07 PM: Creating an optimized production build...
(...)
12:21:26 PM: Failed to compile.
(...)
12:21:26 PM: npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
12:21:26 PM: npm ERR! errno 1
12:21:26 PM: npm ERR! synergy_react@0.1.0 build: `react-scripts build`
12:21:26 PM: npm ERR! Exit status 1
12:21:26 PM: npm ERR!
12:21:26 PM: npm ERR! Failed at the synergy_react@0.1.0 build script.
12:21:26 PM: npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
12:21:26 PM: npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
12:21:26 PM: npm ERR!     /opt/buildhome/.npm/_logs/2021-03-06T03_21_26_431Z-debug.log
12:21:26 PM: ​
12:21:26 PM: ────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
12:21:26 PM:   "build.command" failed                                        
12:21:26 PM: ────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
12:21:26 PM: ​
12:21:26 PM:   Error message
12:21:26 PM:   Command failed with exit code 1: npm run build
12:21:26 PM: ​
12:21:26 PM:   Error location
12:21:26 PM:   In Build command from Netlify app:
12:21:26 PM:   npm run build
12:21:26 PM: ​
12:21:26 PM:   Resolved config
12:21:26 PM:   build:
12:21:26 PM:     base: /opt/build/repo/synergy_react
12:21:26 PM:     command: npm run build
12:21:26 PM:     commandOrigin: ui
12:21:26 PM:     publish: /opt/build/repo/synergy_react/build
```

Another strange part is the I also get `Failed to compile` error, but it works perfectly fine in my local server. 
Also, I've tried `CI=npm run build` as well, but didn't work :(

 Any advice? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You’ll need a space after the =, and not one before `CI= npm run build`